# Запуск множества телеграм ботов, с возможностью обновления

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я использую модуль **python-telegram-bot**. Суть в том, что нужно запустить очень много ботов, при этом, с возможностью запустить нового бота, или удалить старого.

Простенький пример кода:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater

# будем считать, что это обращение к БД из которой вытаскиваем список токенов
tokens = get_tokens()

# перебираем токены
for token in tokens:
  # инициализируем текущего бота
  updater = Updater(
      token=token
  )
  # запускает пулллинг
  updater.start_polling()
```

Таким образом, получается запустить кучку ботов, однако, возникает вопрос: А как их обновлять без полного перезапуска? Абстрактно представляю, что нужно сделать, но не представляю как, особенно в текущем контексте(

Кто-то уже делал нечто подобное? Хотелось бы увидеть пример.

Comment: Поясните, что значит "обновлять без перезапуска"?

Comment: @RomanKonoval. Имеется в виду, инициализация нового бота, или удаление какого-нибудь существующего, делая всё это на лету, не затрагивая соседних ботов. В текущем примере, чтобы запустились новые боты, необходимо останавливать скрипт и запускать повторно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы запустить бота, нужно создать новый объект `Updater` и вызвать у него метод `start_polling`. Чтобы остановить бота нужно у объекта `Updater` вызвать метод `stop`.

Программа при старте читает список ботов из базы даных и запускает их.
Далее, пока пользователь не остановит программу, она должна быть запущена, т.е. ждать сигнала окончания программы.

Нужен какой-то способ сообщать программе, чтобы она запустила нового бота или остановила уже запущенного. Для этого, во-первых, нужно как-то идентифицировать ботов, т.е. для запущеного бота хранить его идентификатор или имя, чтобы можно было на него ссылаться. Во-вторых, нужно хранить все созданные объекты `Updater`, чтобы их использовать для остановки бота.

Вот схема как это можно сделать:

```
# bot_infos это список объектов каждый из которых описывает бота 
# и содержит как минимум token i id бота
bot_infos = get_bots_infos_from_db()
# тут храним все объекты Updater. ключом служит id бота
updaters = {}

for bot_info in bot_infos:
  # инициализируем текущего бота
  updater = Updater(
      token=bot_info.token
  )
  # запускает пулллинг
  updater.start_polling()
  updaters[bot_info.id] = updater

while(True):
   # command это объект который содержит тип команды и ее параметры
   # например, для команды new_bot параметры - идентификатор и токен
   command = read_command_from_console()

   if (command.type == 'quit'):
      break

   if (command.type == 'new_bot'):
      add_new_bot_to_db(command.params['id'], command.params['token'])
      updater = Updater(token=command.params['token']))
      updater.start_polling()
      updaters[command.params['id'] = updater

   if (command.type == 'stop_bot'):
      updater = updaters[command.params['id']]
      updater.stop()
```